# grey 'dotted' table border won't disappear

Tags: html

I am just editing a slideshow and I want to add borders of my choice and remove the underlying grey dotted table and on some slides I can make the table transparent using "border-color: transparent;" and it disappears and in this case, I cannot. Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong? I also want to be able to keep the purple outside border but it seems to disappear and the dotted line remains EVERY TIME! SOS!

```
<div id="main" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; text-align:left; ">
<div id="col1" style=" float:left;padding: 30px 30px 0px 0px;">
<div class="col_content img_container" style="min-width: 300px;">
<div class="interactive_image" data-l="855" data-t="295" id="interactive_image_2" name="interactive_image" poster="" src="" style="position: absolute; top: 295px; left: 855px">&nbsp;</div>
<img alt="Two male co-worker communicating in office kitchen" src="/learning_modules/3969/course_175403_ZWRzZ2RwNEkzZzNknJmnl5c=/pages/images/two_men_communicating_in_office_kitchen.png" style="height: 480px; width: 436px;" /></div>
</div>

<div id="col2" style="padding: 25px 30px 25px 30px;  /* float: right; */ ">
<div class="col_content">
<h1>Unit 4: Developing Effective Communication Skills</h1>

<p>Most people are not naturally gifted communicators. Developing effective communication skills begins with simple interactions and can be practised every day in settings that range from social to professional.</p>

<p>To practise your communication skills, you might like to:</p>

<ul>
    <li>Ask a trusted friend to give you feedback on your communication style and skills. This feedback can be very useful, as we often do not really know how we appear to others;</li>
    <li>Videotape yourself having a conversation. When you review the recording, you should note what your words and body language may be communicating and identify any areas for further development;</li>
    <li>Practise in front of a mirror.</li>
</ul>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border: 2px solid #1774c6; background: #F0F0F0; -moz-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px;  width: 490px; height: auto; margin: 25px auto 0;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 75%; padding: 24px; vertical-align: middle;">
            <p style="margin:0;">Why should you practise your communication skills?</p>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 25%; padding: 24px; vertical-align: middle;">
            <div><a class="button2 inline-tip" href="#" id="tip-1" tabindex="1">Answer</a></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<style type="text/css">.button2 {
        font-size: 1.2em;
        width: 120px;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 2px solid #1774c6;
    background: #1774c6;
    color:#fff !important;
    font-weight:normal !important;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 6px 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.button2:hover {
    background-color:#1774c6;
    color:#fff !important;
    font-weight:normal !important;
    text-decoration:none;
    width: 120px;
}

.button2:focus {
text-decoration:none !important;
outline: 0;

}

hr {
    margin-top: 5px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 2px solid #1774c6;
}
</style>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPsP0.png)

Comment: In which browser you viewed this?

Comment: There is no CSS in that code that would make a dotted line, so you must be leaving something out. Is this for HTML in an e-mail? If yes, you need to tell us, because that changes a lot of things. There are also several things you should try/do: A) Use the browsers CSS inspector to find where the dotted line comes from. B) Stop using inline CSS. Mixing it with a style sheet makes everything just more difficult. C) Stop using tables for layout. D) Provide a working [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) that shows the problem.

Comment: @DulanJay because it is our HRIS system, it is cloud-based but I use Chrome.